# How to handle IIF or Switch divide by zero giving #ERROR?

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2008, ssrs-2008-r2

I tried using `IIF` and `Switch` case, but I am unable to handle N/A case when there would be a divide by zero error. For example:

```
=switch(
    ReportItems!Textbox54.Value = 0, "N/A",
    ReportItems!Textbox54.Value <> 0, ((ReportItems!Textbox56.Value) / (ReportItems!Textbox54.Value)))
```

I am getting N/A with out this:

```
ReportItems!Textbox54.Value <> 0, ((ReportItems!Textbox56.Value) / (ReportItems!Textbox54.Value)
```

But if add this condition I am getting an error?

I am using SSRS 2008 R2.

Output:

> 19.47%
>     13.85%
>     #Error

Comment: What is the value for `56` and `54` in that third case?

Comment: @jeroen both are zeros  in error place

Answer (score 8):

The problem with the IIF function is that it is a *function* not a language construct. This means that it **evaluates both parameters** before passing the parameters to the function. Consequently, if you have a divide by zero error, this will get evaluated and cause an `#ERROR` condition even when it looks like that code shouldn't be executed due to boolean condition of the `IIF` statement.

There are two workarounds for this problem:

**IIF bypass**

Basically make two IIF function calls where you won't get divide by zero errors:

```
=IIF(ReportItems!Textbox54.Value <> 0, 
    ReportItems!Textbox56.Value / IIF(ReportItems!Textbox54.Value = 0, 1, ReportItems!Textbox54.Value),
    "N/A")
```

So where ReportItems!Textbox54.Value is zero, divide by 1 instead, throw that result away and use N/A.

**Custom Code**

Create a safe divide by zero function in custom code where you can use real language constructs.

```
Public Function SafeDivide(ByVal Numerator As Decimal, ByVal Denominator As Decimal) As Decimal
    If Denominator = 0 Then
       Return 0
    End If
    Return (Numerator / Denominator)
End Function
```

and then use this in your report for the Value expression instead of IIF or SWITCH:

```
=Code.SafeDivide(ReportItems!Textbox56.Value, ReportItems!Textbox54.Value)
```

and use a Format string to display zeroes as "N/A":

```
#,##0.00;-#,##0.00;N/A
```

Comment: +1 for custom code. A much more pragmatic, versatile and **UNDER USED** facility. Not to mention under developed...

Comment: While I like the elegance of the Custom Code, a result of 0 is ambiguous - it could result from  0/5 (a genuine 0%) or 5/0 (a N/A result).  The genuine 0% would be formatted as N/A.

Answer (score 0):

try the below code

```
  =IIF(ReportItems!Textbox54.Value = 0,nothing, IIF(ReportItems!Textbox54.Value = 0,1,ReportItems!Textbox56.Value) / IIF(ReportItems!Textbox54.Value = 0,1,ReportItems!Textbox54.Value) )
```

never zero condition