# SSRS 2008 - error message when dividing by zero

Tags: reporting-services

In my Texbox expression, giving divide by zero errors, I had:

```
 =SUM ((Sum( IIF(Fields!Pay.Value = "G" , Fields!EndBal.Value * 1, Fields!EndBal.Value * 0  ))  - Sum( IIF(Fields!Pay.Value = "N" , Fields!EndBal.Value * 1, Fields!EndBal.Value * 0  ))  )  /   (Sum( IIF(Fields! Pay.Value = "G" , Fields!EndBal.Value * 1, Fields!EndBal.Value * 0  ))) )
```

**Solution**:
In the Menu > Report > Report Properties > Code I pasted the below code:

```
Public Function Divider (ByVal Dividend As Double, ByVal Divisor As Double)
If IsNothing(Divisor) Or Divisor = 0
  Return 0
Else
  Return Dividend/Divisor
End If
End Function
```

In the Texbox expression now I have entered this, calling the function created:

```
 =code.divider((Sum( IIF(Fields!Pay.Value = "G" , Fields!EndBal.Value * 1, Fields!EndBal.Value * 0  ))  - Sum( IIF(Fields!Pay.Value = "N" , Fields!EndBal.Value * 1, Fields!EndBal.Value * 0  ))  )  ,  (Sum( IIF(Fields!Pay.Value = "G" , Fields!EndBal.Value * 1, Fields!EndBal.Value * 0  ))) )
```

It still gives me the error when dividing by zero. What am I doing wrong here? Am I also missing the total sum, which I had in the first expression.
thank you!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to handle IIF or Switch divide by zero giving #ERROR?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15750896/how-to-handle-iif-or-switch-divide-by-zero-giving-error)

Comment: Nope. In his `IIF()` statements there are no divisions. This happens outside the `IIF()`

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me:

```
= Sum(
    Code.Divider(
      Sum( 
        IIF(
          Fields!Pay.Value = "G" , Fields!EndBal.Value * 1, Fields!EndBal.Value * 0
        )
      ) - Sum(
        IIF(
          Fields!Pay.Value = "N" , Fields!EndBal.Value * 1, Fields!EndBal.Value * 0
        )
      ), Sum( 
        IIF(
          Fields! Pay.Value = "G" , Fields!EndBal.Value * 1, Fields!EndBal.Value * 0 
        )
      )
    )
  )
```

But your total `Sum()` before the divider doesn't do anything, cause you divided the aggregated values already.

Comment: Can you for testing purposes try this code `Sum(IIF(Fields!Pay.Value = "G", Fields!EndBal.Value * 1, Fields!EndBal.Value * 0)) - Sum(IIF(Fields!Pay.Value = "N" , Fields!EndBal.Value * 1, Fields!EndBal.Value * 0)) + Sum(IIF(Fields! Pay.Value = "G" , Fields!EndBal.Value * 1, Fields!EndBal.Value * 0))` and check if it works. If yes, then its caused by the `Divider()`.

Comment: thank you for your help, this test idea using plus sign help me to be aware of my data.

Answer (score -1):

I had a fix on my data and it actually works now , using the same I was trying before:

```
 =code.divider((Sum( IIF(Fields!Pay.Value = "G" , Fields!EndBal.Value * 1, Fields!EndBal.Value * 0  ))  - Sum( IIF(Fields!Pay.Value = "N" , Fields!EndBal.Value * 1, Fields!EndBal.Value * 0  ))  )  ,  (Sum( IIF(Fields!Pay.Value = "G" , Fields!EndBal.Value * 1, Fields!EndBal.Value * 0  ))) )
```

==> it does not needs the SUM in the beggining.