# Calculate time difference between 2 columns in SSRS

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2012, ssrs-tablix, reportingservices-2005

I've got two fields that are calculated as per the below:

> =Format(DateAdd("s", Sum(Fields!TalkTime.Value) / Sum(Fields!EmployeesWorked.Value), "00:00:00"), "HH:mm:ss")

and

> =PREVIOUS(Format(DateAdd("s", Sum(Fields!TalkTime.Value) / Sum(Fields!EmployeesWorked.Value), "00:00:00"), "HH:mm:ss"),
>   "Quarter1")

I've got a separate column to calculate the difference between the 2 columns:

> =ReportItems!Textbox2625.Value - ReportItems!Textbox29.Value

However, when I run the report, the column that I used to calculate the difference between the 2 fields shows '#Error'. I'm assuming there's some kind of formatting problem, but I'm not sure how to fix it?

Comment: You need to use datediff.. something like (datediff("mm",ReportItems!Textbox2625.Value , ReportItems!Textbox29.Value)  . I'm purely running off the top of my head and can't check it at the moment..  but it could be MM instead of mm

Answer (score 0):

`Format` returns a string, so you aren't trying to subtract two dates, you are trying to subtract two strings, which is throwing an error.

Firstly, use a date calculation for the `Value` expression:

```
=DateAdd("s", Sum(Fields!TalkTime.Value) / Sum(Fields!EmployeesWorked.Value), "00:00:00")
```

This calulates the `Sum` of the TalkTime over the `Sum` of the EmployeesWorked time for the scope of the textbox.

Put the formating into the `Format` property: `HH:mm:ss`

This separates the value of the textbox (the time) from its presentation. Now you might be able to do your calculation:

```
=ReportItems!Textbox2625.Value - ReportItems!Textbox29.Value
```

Again, put the formating into the `Format` property: `HH:mm:ss` so it displays as a time.

If this doesn't work, put the calculation in full (excluding the `Format` functions, but see note below on why you might not be using the `Previous` function correctly):

```
=DateAdd("s", Sum(Fields!TalkTime.Value) / Sum(Fields!EmployeesWorked.Value), "00:00:00") 
- PREVIOUS(DateAdd("s", Sum(Fields!TalkTime.Value) / Sum(Fields!EmployeesWorked.Value), "00:00:00"), "Quarter1")
```

Note that aggregating within the `Previous` function and specifying the scope (in this instance "Quarter1") requires the specified scope ("Quarter1") to be a containing scope for the current scope of that ReportItem.

For example, you might have a table with three nested levels of grouping: by Year, then by Month, then by Day. The expression `=Previous(Sum(Fields!Sales.Value, "Day"), "Year")` in a row associated with the group `Day` will return the sales value for the same day and month for the scope of previous year.

If expression contains an aggregate function that specifies a scope other than the default, the scope parameter for the Previous function must be a containing scope for the scope specified in the aggregate function call - in other words, the textboxes must be in a child scope of the "Quarter1" scope. While I don't know the scoping you are using, from your wording it looks like you are trying to get the calculation from a dataset which has the value from the first quarter, not a containing group scope? If so, you don't need the `Previous` function, you can just calculate the aggregate over the entire dataset "Quarter1" in the `Sum` function like so:

```
=DateAdd("s", Sum(Fields!TalkTime.Value, "Quarter1") / Sum(Fields!EmployeesWorked.Value, "Quarter1"), "00:00:00"))
```

Comment: Thanks Chris, I used =DateAdd("s", Sum(Fields!TalkTime.Value) / Sum(Fields!EmployeesWorked.Value), "00:00:00") to get the formatting right. Now I do this calculation without getting an error: =ReportItems!Textbox2625.Value - ReportItems!Textbox29.Value  . To finish my calculation I need needed to slightly alter my formula: =ReportItems!Textbox2625.Value - ReportItems!Textbox29.Value  / ReportItems!Textbox29.Value  - now I once again get an error if I try to use division. Can you help please?

Comment: Can Textbox29 be zero? You might be getting a divide-by-zero error. [Try one of the strategies in this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15750896/how-to-handle-iif-or-switch-divide-by-zero-giving-error/15753601#15753601)